# Enable parent scrolling when <md-menu> is shown

Tags: angular-material

Is there any way to enable parent scrolling when `<md-menu>` is shown? By looking at source code I see there is [`disableParentScroll`](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/v1.1.1/src/components/menu/js/menuServiceProvider.js#L34) parameter, which is set to `true` by default. Not sure how to override this setting. I guess it should be possible to do somehow globally via `$mdMenuProvider`. Any help would be appreciated.